# How to change domain.com/en/example1 to domain.com/english/example1

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress with many articles I want to change **En** to **English** without changing **example1** using htacess

Example: How to change domain.com/**en**/example1 to domain.com/**english**/example1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples. Please make sure you clear your cache of your browser before testing your urls.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:en/)(example1.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/english/%1 [L]
```

OR to catch everything and anything after `en` then use following. make sure you use either first set of Rules or these following.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(?:en/)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/english/%1 [L]
```

Comment: @YahmisYahaya, could you please check now, I have edited solutions now, let me know on same, how it goes?

Comment: Wow I really appreciate, It works successfully with option 2 above, I also used the below code to also redirect en.example.com/example1 to example.com/english/example1

>RewriteBase /
>RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.en\.example\.com$
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/english$1" [R=301,L]
>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/en/(.*/?)$ [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/english/%1 [L]
>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*/?)$ [NC]
>RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/english/%1 [L]

Is there any best solution to this?

Comment: @YahmisYahaya, I am happy to help you. request you to have 1 question 1 post only, for new question you could open a new post., cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @YahmisYahaya, Your welcome, glad that I could help you. Keep learning and keep sharing on this great forum, cheers.